# In pelles c windows.h doesn't compile

Tags: c, header-files, pelles-c

I'm using pelles c. when I compile this code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{
   printf("Hello World");
}
```

I get this error:

```
D:\Program Files\PellesC\Include\Win\basetsd.h(53): error #2001: Syntax error: expected ';' but found 'INT64'.
D:\Program Files\PellesC\Include\Win\basetsd.h(53): warning #2099: Missing type specifier; assuming 'int'.
D:\Program Files\PellesC\Include\Win\basetsd.h(57): error #2120: Redeclaration of '__int64', previously declared at D:\Program Files\PellesC\Include\Win\basetsd.h(53); expected 'int' but found 'unsigned int'.
D:\Program Files\PellesC\Include\Win\basetsd.h(57): error #2001: Syntax error: expected ';' but found 'UINT64'.
D:\Program Files\PellesC\Include\Win\basetsd.h(57): warning #2099: Missing type specifier; assuming 'int'.
D:\Program Files\PellesC\Include\Win\winnt.h(558): fatal error #1014: #error: "No target architecture".
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Remove `#include <windows.h>` and compile again. Does the same error occur?

Comment: yes it will compile but i want to use windows.h

Comment: @nima, for what purpose? include header files when you need it.

Comment: my purpose is to place the cursor on different locations on the screen and put some characters there. Solutions I found use windows.h . Can you help me with that.

Comment: `windows.h` contains function names that pertains to the Windows API. It has nothing to do with screen location.

Comment: IT's NOT VOID main( ), it's INT main( ), like this:

Comment: int main( int argc, char **argv ) { ... return 0; or return 1; }

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to use `windows.h` in `PellesC` you have to go to:

- Project -> Project Options -> Compiler
- Check: Enable Microsoft Extensions

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some `#define`s which other compilers (e.g. Visual Studio) always define. They provide essential information about the processor architecture, the OS version, the SDK version etc.

It's probably best to look up the Microsoft documentation about what macros their compiler defines and do the same.

This [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) could be a good starting point.

Answer (score -2):

1. Initialize your program by using `int main(void)` and not `void main(void)`
2. You are missing your return statement of `return(0);` just before your last bracket. You must include this or you will get a syntax error because your program does not know when to stop running.

Then do the following

1. From your pull down menu bar select `Project` then scroll down and select `Project Options.
2. Select the `Compiler` tab and make sure that the `Calling conv:` box has `_cdecl` selected.
3. Click on the `linker` tab and make sure that in the `subsystem` box the type is set to `Console`.

Try building it again and see what happens!

Comment: Only your third item *might* be correct (I don't know). I *do* know that your #1 and #2 are wrong, though. You can certainly use `void main(void)` and, if you do so, there is no need for a `return [int]` statement at all; when does the program exit? Simple: When `main` exits, which is at the end of the function.